How to evaluate integral: $\Omega=\int^{\infty}_0 \text{arccot}(px)\frac{\tan(x)}{r^2\sin^2(x)+q^2\cos^2(x)}dx$
How to evaluate integral $$\Omega=\int^{\infty}_0 \text{arccot}(px)\frac{\tan(x)}{r^2\sin^2(x)+q^2\cos^2(x)}dx$$
I don't have any tricks for this integration it seems very difficult to me, I tried using the usual tricks but they didn't all work
This problem is from a book.Table of Integrals, Series, and Products Eighth Edition page 608
in book :
$$\Omega = \frac{\pi}{2r^2}\ln\left({1+\frac{r}{q}\tanh\left({\frac{1}{p}}\right)}\right)$$

Difficult indeed.  After multiple layers of substitution, I've "simplified" the integral to
$$\Omega=-i\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{z(z^2 - 1)\log(\frac{p\log(z) - 1}{p\log(z) + 1})}{(z^2 + 1)((q^2-r^2)z^4 + 2(z^2 + r^2)z^2 + q^2 - r^2)} ~dz$$
I can't figure out where to go from there.

In case it helps, $$\operatorname{arccot}(x) = -i \log(\frac{-1 - ix}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}})$$

@Dan I think this doesn't help, it just makes things more complicated.

$\DeclareMathOperator{\arccot}{arccot}$
$$\Omega = \int_{0}^{\infty}\arccot(px)\frac{\tan(x)}{r^2\sin^2(x)+q^2\cos^2(x)}dx = 
\frac{1}{q^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\arccot(px)\frac{\tan(x)\sec^2(x)}{\frac{r^2}{q^2}\tan^2(x)+1}dx$$
Doing integration by parts we get
$$\Omega=\frac{1}{q^2}\left[\arccot(px)\cdot\frac{q^2}{2r^2}\ln\left(1+\frac{r^2}{q^2}\tan^2(x)\right)\right]_{0}^{\infty}-\frac{1}{q^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{-p}{1+p^2x^2}\cdot\frac{q^2}{2r^2}\ln\left(1+\frac{r^2}{q^2}\tan^2(x)\right)dx$$
The first part evaluates to zero, and we can simplify the second part to get
$$\Omega = \frac{p}{2r^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{r^2}{q^2}\tan^2(x)\right)}{1+p^2x^2}dx$$
We can break up the integral into $\pi$ sized chunks, taking advantage of the periodicity of $\tan$
$$\Omega=
\frac{p}{2r^2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{r^2}{q^2}\tan^2(x)\right)}{1+p^2x^2}dx=
\frac{p}{2r^2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{r^2}{q^2}\tan^2(x)\right)}{1+p^2(x+k\pi)^2}dx$$
Rescaling with $x\rightarrow\pi x$
$$\tag{1}\Omega=
\frac{p\pi}{2r^2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{r^2}{q^2}\tan^2(\pi x)\right)}{1+(p\pi)^2(x+k)^2}dx$$
Using the transformation $x\rightarrow 1-x$
$$\Omega=
\frac{p\pi}{2r^2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{r^2}{q^2}\tan^2(\pi (1-x))\right)}{1+(p\pi)^2(1-x+k)^2}dx=
\frac{p\pi}{2r^2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{r^2}{q^2}\tan^2(\pi x)\right)}{1+(p\pi)^2(x-(k+1))^2}dx$$
We can rewrite the limits of the summation to get
$$\tag{2}\Omega=
\frac{p\pi}{2r^2}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{r^2}{q^2}\tan^2(\pi x)\right)}{1+(p\pi)^2(x+k)^2}dx$$
Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ together we have
$$2\Omega=
\frac{p\pi}{2r^2}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{r^2}{q^2}\tan^2(\pi x)\right)}{1+(p\pi)^2(x+k)^2}dx$$
Changing the order of integration and summation
$$\Omega=
\frac{p\pi}{4r^2}\int_{0}^{1}\ln\left(1+\frac{r^2}{q^2}\tan^2(\pi x)\right)\left(\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+(p\pi)^2(x+k)^2}\right)dx$$
Let's take a look at that sum
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+(p\pi)^2(x+k)^2}=
\frac{1}{(p\pi)^2}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x+k+\frac{i}{p\pi}}\cdot\frac{1}{x+k-\frac{i}{p\pi}}
$$
With partial fraction decomposition we get
$$\frac{i}{2p\pi}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x+k+\frac{i}{p\pi}}-\frac{1}{x+k-\frac{i}{p\pi}}
$$
Using the fact, that $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x+k}=\pi\cot(\pi x)$
$$\frac{i}{2p\pi}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(x+\frac{i}{p\pi}\right)+k}-\frac{1}{\left(x-\frac{i}{p\pi}\right)+k}=
\frac{i}{2p}\left(\cot\left(\pi x + \frac{i}{p}\right)-\cot\left(\pi x - \frac{i}{p}\right)\right)$$
Using the angle addition formula, this simplifies to
$$\frac{i}{p}\tan\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)\frac{\sec^2(\pi x)}{\tan^2\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)-\tan^2(\pi x)}$$
Using the identity $\tanh(x)=-i\tan(ix)$ we get
$$\frac{1}{p}\tanh\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)\frac{\sec^2(\pi x)}{\tanh^2\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)+\tan^2(\pi x)}$$
Substituting this back in the integral we have
$$\Omega=\frac{\pi \tanh\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)}{4r^2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{r^2}{q^2}\tan^2(\pi x)\right)\sec^2(\pi x)}{\tanh^2\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)+\tan^2(\pi x)}dx$$
Since the integrand is symmetric around $\frac{1}{2}$
$$\Omega=\frac{\pi \tanh\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)}{2r^2}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{r^2}{q^2}\tan^2(\pi x)\right)\sec^2(\pi x)}{\tanh^2\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)+\tan^2(\pi x)}dx$$
Substituting $t=\tan(\pi x)$
$$\Omega=\frac{\tanh\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)}{2r^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{r^2}{q^2}t^2\right)}{\tanh^2\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)+t^2}dt$$
Finally, we can finish this off using Feynman's trick.
Let
$$\Omega(\lambda)=\frac{\tanh\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)}{2r^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+\lambda^2t^2\right)}{\tanh^2\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)+t^2}dt$$
We have $\Omega(0)=0$ and $\Omega(\frac{r}{q})=\Omega$. Taking the derivative with respect to $\lambda$ we get
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{d\lambda}\left(\Omega(\lambda)\right)&=
\frac{d}{d\lambda}\left(\frac{\tanh\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)}{2r^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+\lambda^2t^2\right)}{\tanh^2\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)+t^2}dt\right)=
\frac{\tanh\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)}{2r^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}\left(\frac{\ln\left(1+\lambda^2t^2\right)}{\tanh^2\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)+t^2}\right)dt \\
&=
\frac{\tanh\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)}{2r^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2\lambda t^2}{(1+\lambda^2t^2)\left(\tanh^2\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)+t^2\right)}dt
\end{align}
Using partial fraction decomposition
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{d\lambda}\left(\Omega(\lambda)\right) & =
\frac{\tanh\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)}{r^2}\frac{\lambda}{1-\lambda^2\tanh^2\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+\lambda^2t^2}-\frac{\tanh^2\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)}{\tanh^2\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)+t^2}dt \\
& = \frac{\tanh\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)}{r^2}\frac{\lambda}{1-\lambda^2\tanh^2\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)}\left[\frac{\arctan(\lambda t)}{\lambda}-\tanh\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)\arctan\left(\frac{t}{\tanh\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)}\right)\right]_{0}^{\infty} \\
& = \frac{\tanh\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)}{r^2}\frac{\lambda}{1-\lambda^2\tanh^2\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)}\left(\frac{\pi}{2\lambda}-\frac{\tanh\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)\pi}{2}\right) \\
& = \frac{\pi}{2r^2}\frac{\tanh\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)}{1+\tanh\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)\lambda}
\end{align}
Integrating back with respect to $\lambda$
$$\Omega(\lambda)=\frac{\pi}{2r^2}\int\frac{\tanh\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)}{1+\tanh\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)\lambda}d\lambda
=\frac{\pi}{2r^2}\ln\left(1+\tanh\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)\lambda\right)+C$$
We have that $\Omega(0)=C=0$, and so, finally
$$\Omega=\Omega\left(\frac{r}{q}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2r^2}\ln\left(1+\frac{r}{q}\tanh\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)\right)$$
